# How to remove TFS 2015 Update 3 and SharePoint 2013 integration?

Tags: sharepoint, tfs, sharepoint-2013

I have TFS 2015 Update 3 configured with SharePoint 2013 integration. I am planning to upgrade to TFS 2018 in new hardware, which does not support SharePoint integration.

According to MS [documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/sharepoint-dashboards/deprecation/disable-tfs-sharepoint-integration-after-tfs-2018-upgrade) I should upgrade and disable the SharePoint integration post upgrade.

In my case I am upgrading and moving to new hardware at the same time. When I am moving to a new set of hardware, I do not want to bring the OLD SharePoint along.

So before even upgrading to TFS 2018 I want to decouple SharePoint sites from the existing TFS 2015 Update 3 configuration.

Is there a way to achieve this? or my approach is wrong?

Comment: Are you going to continue to use SharePoint for anything else?

Comment: For some time yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need SharePoint anymore, you could remove SharePoint extension in your TFS 2015 by going to TFS Administration Console, click SharePoint Web Applications, click Modify against your server connection and choose Remove.

If you still need TFS SharePoint sites, you should follow the document you mentioned to disable SharePoint integration.

It's suggested have a full backup of your database, and do a dryrun upgrade before using in production environment.

Comment: I tried the disable TFS integration, and it worked in TFS 2015 without even being upgraded to TFS 2018. So i will let users use for some time as readonly then we will think of moving the document to other tools.